# Reset list-style so ol[type="1"], ol[type="A"] works

Tags: css

I have a stylesheet that has the following reset:

```
ol, ul {
   list-style: none;
}
```

Is there a particular css rule that will override this so that the following works:

```
<ol type="A"></ol>
```

should be styled accordingly:

```
ol {
   list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give a **class**:

```
.upper-alpha {
   list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```

```
<ol type="A" class="upper-alpha"></ol>
```

Or, use the **unreset method**:

```
ol[type="A"] {
   list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ol[type="A"],
.upper-alpha {
  list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```

```html
<ol type="A">
  <li>Hello</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I ended up going with the method of ol[type="A"], but was hoping there was a cleaner reset. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @DevOtts These are the only types... `:)`